# IE8 Bookmarklet: Cannot drag to bookmark bar

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, bookmarklet

So my last attempt at asking this question was vague. So I'll try this again.

I have created a system that makes use of a bookmarklet for populating. Now, in all major browsers (excl. IE8), you can drag/add the bookmarklet to the favourites with no problem. Even when trying to add it manually, it doesn't seem to work. Is this a code issue?

Here is the bookmarklet code:

```
javascript:var metatags, my_arr=document.getElementsByTagName('META'), sel=document.selection.createRange().text,d=document, f, counter;
for(counter=0;counter<my_arr.length;counter++)
{
    if(my_arr[counter].name.toLowerCase()=='description')
    {
        metatags=my_arr[counter].content;
    }
}
f='http://xxxxxxxxxxx.co.za/common/UserControls/ShareThis/ShareThis.aspx', l=d.location, e=encodeURIComponent,u=f+'?u='+e(l.href)+'&t='+e(d.title)+'&s='+e(sel.length<1?metatags?metatags:'':sel)+'&v=4';

a=function()
{
    if(!window.open(u, 't', 'toolbar=0, resizable=1, scrollbars=1, status=1, width=720, height=570'))
        l.href=u;
};
a();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the bookmarklet, and choose "Add to Favorites". Then click the new bookmark. If it doesn't work, it is a code issue.

Also, generally, copy/paste into IE8 url bar should work as well.

I tested your bookmarklet and it worked fine. Below is what I used and tested and it worked. I tested by copy/paste into the URL bar.

```
javascript:var metatags,my_arr=document.getElementsByTagName('META'),sel=document.selection.createRange().text,d=document,f,counter;for(counter=0;counter<my_arr.length;counter++){if(my_arr[counter].name.toLowerCase()=='description'){metatags=my_arr[counter].content}}f='http://xxxxxxxxxxx.co.za/common/UserControls/ShareThis/ShareThis.aspx',l=d.location,e=encodeURIComponent,u=f+'?u='+e(l.href)+'&t='+e(d.title)+'&s='+e(sel.length<1?metatags?metatags:'':sel)+'&v=4';a=function(){if(!window.open(u,'t','toolbar=0, resizable=1, scrollbars=1, status=1, width=720, height=570'))l.href=u};a();
```

Sometimes bookmarklet problems are related to conversion of the readable code into bookmarklet format. I created above using http://javascriptcompressor.com/

Comment: Thanks. When I do that, it adds a link to the page, and not to the JS. I'm going to try and clean up some other things and see if that works.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "adds a link to... the JS". That doesn't make sense. Anyway... please accept my answer by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: I mean that the link that it adds as a bookmark is to the current page, and not the javascript of the bookmarklet. But this no longer matters as I have managed another solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: To create a bookmarklet on a page, put the code in the  href. Example: `<a href="javascript:/*yourcode*/">a bookmarklet</a>`. If you right click on such a link and choose to add to favorites, a bookmark with that js code should be added to the favorites. If not, something is unusual about your IE, or you are making a user error. Also, thanks for accepting my answer.